# Change li height on browser width resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made a little script to change the height of a group of li-elements to the one with the most content.

The code works fine, but it should also work by resizing the browser width.

I need to  know why it doesn't reload by changing the browser width ?

Here is my Code :

```
//changes slider hight to the hight of the li with the most content
function heightChange() {
    var max = -1;
    $(".feedback li").each(function() {
        var h = $(this).height(); 
        max = h > max ? h : max;
    });
    $(".feedback li").css("height", max);
};

// start by open site
heightChange();

// load function by resizing of the browser window
$(window).bind("resize", function(){
    heightChange();
});
```

Comment: can you post a fiddlejs whit html and javascript?

what should happen if change width and not height?

Comment: why do you think should it happen something after the first function call? you set `max = h` at the first call, then `h` doesn't change

Comment: Seems absolutely fine to me, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J7RUt/

Comment: Works fine for mee too http://jsfiddle.net/rUbt5/

Comment: Once the height is set, it also will be returned in your height() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your height before setting it again. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/greVa/)**

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
     $(".feedback li").css("height", "auto");
    heightChange();
});
```

Otherwise will `height()` just return the specified value;

Also, `.on()` is the preferred way to bind and event, as of jQuery 1.7